# Can the contents of the NSCachesDirectory be deleted by the system while the app is open?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

As title.

Is it possible that files that I store in the `NSCachesDirectory` can be deleted by the system (i.e. in low storage situations), **while my is running in the foreground?**

Comment: cool question. I would say: NOO -- that'd break many apps but I dont know for sure

Comment: It's not possible to answer this without knowing what the files being cached are and how they are used.  It's possible, of course, but you'd need to make sure you weren't using them at the time.

Comment: Not 100% if you can go by this but you could try to simulate a memory warning in the ios simulator.

Comment: @BooRanger I believe low memory situations are different from low storage situations.  I do not think it is possible to simulate low storage (please someone correct me if Im wrong)

Comment: @trojanfoe So for example if I were using FMDB, the underlying databas can not be deleted between if execution is between `[db open]` and `[db close]`?

Comment: Hopefully iOS is smart enough, on low storage conditions, to purge tmp and Library/Caches folders only for apps that aren't loaded into memory (foreground or background). But I don't know this for sure. This might be a good question to post on the Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: @Robert: Well it might possibly work! Under UNIX you can `unlink()` an open file and the filename will disappear from the directory, however the file will operate as normal all the time the file descriptor is open.  This, however won't give you what you want, as it won't reclaim any disk space!

Comment: @rmaddy Good idea... I posted it here https://devforums.apple.com/thread/179078

Answer (score 2):

[File System programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. **This will never occur while an app is running.** However, you should be aware that iTunes restore is not necessarily the only condition under which the Caches directory can be erased.

So the answer is - No, it is not possible for the NSCachesDirectory to be deleted while the app is running in the foreground.

However their wording is slightly ambiguous with regard to the app running in the background.

Comment: I disagree.  The caches directory is for the sole use of the app and some of the files in it can be deleted if they are of no value.  This depends entirely on the app's use of those files, but it's not correct to state that the directory cannot be deleted (in fact your question asks if files within the directory can be deleted, so it's ambiguous anyway).

Comment: Good points. The contents of the folder deleted by the system is what I meant.... Ill update the question.